# "In use" in Additional Drivers, but not actually used?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lspci, additional-drivers

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. I'm attempting to use the proprietary NVIDIA drivers for my video card. I've gone through the Additional Drivers and selected the appropriate version, then clicked the "Apply Changes" button and waited for it to finish. After the progress bar finishes, it looks like this:

[image: What my Additional Drivers box looks like]

In this image, one can see that the driver is now "in use". After rebooting, I've run `lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12` with the following output:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 980] [10de:13c0] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device [3842:2983]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at ce000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at fea80000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

As can be seen, there is no `Kernel driver in use:` line.

I've installed `linux-headers-4.2.0-22` and `ubuntu-restricted-extras` as suggested [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia), with no different results.  That site also suggests running `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, a program which I don't have.

I've tried going back to the Nouveau display driver and that will not be used either.

What is causing this mismatched reporting of driver status?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute :

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

The output shows something like :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 3501
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

Now you can see the drivers in use.

**Update addressing your feedback that there is no listed NVIDIA 3D controller for GTX 980 :**

Generally you should use the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories. But when you have problems with these drivers, you can install the more current drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA. This often leads to properly working graphics, especially on very new NVIDIA GEFORCE adapters.

**Step 1 : Uninstall the installed NVIDIA drivers.**

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

**Step 2 : Install the latest official NVIDIA drivers.**

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I run into the same issue; there is no listed Kernel driver in use for the `VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation`.  There is no listed 3D controller.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you solved your problem or not. I met the same issue, and finally found out that I didn't install the nvidia driver correctly. During the installation, when prompted with disabling secure boot, we will choose yes and type in the password. But each time when I reboot, I'll just continue secure boot, and didn't turn to disabling secure boot. When I turned off secure boot, everything is fine now.

Comment: A detailed description of steps taken is necessary to properly answer this question. Such as add Nvidia ppa and get driver 999.99, etc.